# Initialize a constant variable in PS_CONFIGURATION

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In fact my question is facing a misunderstanding concerning **the functioning of prestashop**, in particular due to the **poorly** explained documentation. In fact, the final idea would be to create an accordion visible in the front end, with all the necessary parameters via a form in the back office.

I consulted the [getting started](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/) documentation, with success, and my question is about the variable of the table **PS_CONFIGURATION**. To use the example in the doc, when is the variable MY_MODULENAME initialized? I would like to put a variable by input of the form, but when I enter them in the display form method by indicating in the name the name of each variable, I have an error returning undefined. I was told that the variables initialized during installation, but after regularly uninstalling / reinstalling my module, nothing changes, so I put all the variables in the *install()* or *getContent()* method.

So my question is: **In which part of the main class initialized all the necessary variables** (I already know that we must use *!Configuration::updateValue()*), to later use them in the form and transcribe them in the tpl file with smarty **?**

Comment: According to the docs, it is your responsibility to set that in the `install()` method, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @21baki can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand well your question, but maybe this will help you.

in `getContent()` function you generate the content displayed at the Back Office. This is where you build the form to display and get the options.

When the form is submitted something like this should work to save the variables

```
if (Tools::isSubmit($this->name)) {
    // process the submitted data 
}
```

The `install()` function is mainly used to register the hooks and to create the databases, as contrary of `uninstall()` which should remove that data for a clean uninstallation.

On the Front End you depend on the hooks, until the hook is called any variable that you define will not be present in the template, so probably if you see an undefined notice then you are trying to access the variable but is still not assigned.

If you are going to build a module for your site or for a particular client and you don't want to depend on hooks you can assign the variables in the header hook and then you should be able to use then in any part of the tpls.

If you want to build a commercial module, then you must depend on hooks.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your details, they helped me a lot in my research.